# PHP SQL Find Top 5 Most Repeated Values

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I have a database that I am accessing through PHP and mysqli.  I need to get the top 5 most repeated values.

For example,
  the database would have in it
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5,

The database should print out in a row

: 5, 2, 1, 4, 6

Comment: "For example, the database would have in it 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5"… um, what? Databases don't contain a list of things; they contain tables, which contain columns and rows. Are those values of a single column in a single table?

Comment: Do you array of these numbers `1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5,` or they are as string?

Answer (score 2):

Are you asking what the SQL query would be to get most occurances to least?

this here will group by the number and then order it from most occurances to the least

```
SELECT number , count(number) as 'occurrences' 
FROM my_table 
GROUP BY number 
ORDER BY count(number) DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/781001)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$array=array(1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 5, 5, 5, 5);
$data=array_count_values($array);//counting the no. of values in an array
arsort($data);//sorting array in descending order
print_r(array_keys($data));//getting the key of array which is the desired output
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the result as a string (in a row):

```
SELECT STUFF((SELECT ',' + convert(varchar,my_number) FROM my_table group by 
my_number ORDER BY count(my_number) desc for XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
```